# UIDatePicker custom date

Tags: дата, xcode, objective-c

Добрый день. Подскажите как мне установить начальную дату. Изначально стоит "сегодня" А мне нужно аж 1990 год! =(

Зарание благодарен.

Comment: Вам нужно получить NSDate? или начальную дату в UIDatePicker компоненте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDate *someDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1990-01-01"];
NSLog(@"%@", someDate);
[dateFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Смотрите документацию класса [`UIDatePicker`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html).

Там есть свойство `date`:

```
date

The date displayed by the date picker.
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date
Discussion

The default is the date when the UIDatePicker object is created. The date is ignored in the mode UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer; for that mode, the date picker starts at 0:00. Setting this property does not animate the date picker by spinning the wheels to the new date and time; to do that you must use the setDate:animated: method.
```

А вот здесь показывается, как работать с [`NSDate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774556/set-an-nsdate-object-to-custom-date-combined-with-datepicker-date)